# Algorithm to take explicit heights of images and lay them out in optimally compact "Masonry"-style layout

Tags: javascript, algorithm, layout, react-masonry

I am using *[react-masonry-css](https://github.com/paulcollett/react-masonry-css#readme)* to lay out some images in a [Masonry](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-masonry/)-like layout, but it is just putting the same number of images in each column basically, and it ends up having large discrepancies in the amount of space left at the bottom of each column, as seen here (this is the bottom of all the columns):

[image]

(Note, a couple of images in this demo are missing, but even if they are all present, there are large differences in the bottom space remaining).

It [looks like](https://github.com/paulcollett/react-masonry-css/blob/72dd46dc71742af15b4f3cfcdb7681e7be9f7773/src/react-masonry-css.js#L112-L130) all that library does is put an equal number of items in each column, irrespective of the image heights.

I would like for it to distribute the images more optimally, given that I also have included the width and height for each image in the JSON data. How can I use the height to figure out how to optimally place the images in a known number of columns? It seems extremely complicated at first thought, like it would require a sophisticated research-paper-like algorithm. Is that true? If so, what are the general algorithms used to solve this, so I may go about writing a quick implementation in JavaScript? If it's instead straightforward, how is it done?

In my head so far, I would maybe divide the number of images by the number of columns to give the first rough estimate of how many per column. Then I would put one image in each column, so there is one image in each of the seven columns. Then I would lay like bricks across the columns next images. I would do the best to keep the column heights the same high, searching through and selecting images that fit an appropriate height.

That is just brainstorming, but already I can see several holes and pitfalls in that non-workable approach. It seems quite hard, and I am wondering if it's a solved problem though, given the images can be widely varied in height.

The end goal is to have all of the columns be roughly the same height; that's it. As close as possible.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we operationalize “most compact” to mean the shortest bounding box,
then this is an [identical-machines
scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical-machines_scheduling)
problem. Each image corresponds to a job, and each column corresponds to
a machine. The processing time of a job is the height/width ratio of the
corresponding image (plus padding).

Although scheduling is NP-hard, there’s a simple and provably effective
approximation known as [Longest Processing-Time
First](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest-processing-time-first_scheduling).
In terms of your problem, for each image in descending order of
height/width, you assign it to the column that is currently the
shortest. (You can shuffle the order of images in each column at the end
to avoid bias towards taller images.) The bounding box will never be
more than 34% longer than it needs to be (well, maybe a little more
because of the interstitials).

```js
// Set up some test data.
const imageCount = 50;
let images = [];
for (let i = 0; i < imageCount; ++i) {
  // Allow the images to vary in aspect ratio between 5:1 and 1:5.
  images.push({
    id: i,
    width: Math.random() + 0.25,
    height: Math.random() + 0.25,
  });
}

// Parameters.
const columnCount = 10;
const thumbnailWidth = 100;
const interstitialHeight = 10;

// Algorithm begins. Initialize empty columns.
let columns = [];
let columnHeights = [];
for (let j = 0; j < columnCount; ++j) {
  // This height will be correct once the column is nonempty.
  columnHeights.push(-interstitialHeight);
  columns.push([]);
}

// Sort the images by aspect ratio descending.
function aspectRatioDescending(a, b) {
  return b.height / b.width - a.height / a.width;
}
images.sort(aspectRatioDescending);

// Assign each image to a column.
for (const image of images) {
  // Find the shortest column.
  let shortest = 0;
  for (let j = 1; j < columnCount; ++j) {
    if (columnHeights[j] < columnHeights[shortest]) {
      shortest = j;
    }
  }
  // Put the image there.
  columnHeights[shortest] +=
    interstitialHeight + thumbnailWidth * (image.height / image.width);
  columns[shortest].push(image);
}

// Shuffle the columns for aesthetic reasons.
for (const column of columns) {
  for (let k = 1; k < column.length; ++k) {
    const i = Math.floor((k + 1) * Math.random());
    let temp = column[i];
    column[i] = column[k];
    column[k] = temp;
  }
}

const maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, columnHeights);
const minHeight = Math.min.apply(null, columnHeights);
// Analyze the layout.
console.log(
  "// The tallest column is %f%% taller than the shortest.",
  (100 * (maxHeight - minHeight)) / minHeight
);
// The tallest column is 3.030982959129835% taller than the shortest.
```

Comment: [Worked perfectly](https://tune.land/zul), converted into a react component :] THANK YOU. Such an elegant and performance-optimized solution.